# Can the Angular CLI be used to build and deploy on a remote server via ssh?

Tags: angular

I'd like to use the Angular CLI to build the app and deploy it on my remote server via SSH. Is this feature available?

Comment: `ng build && scp -r dist/* whatever.com:/wherever`

Comment: that's great thx you! Cd you post it as an answer?

Comment: Not gonna bother. It's too trivial and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well that answers my question and it is far from trivial (not everybody is used to the CLI).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A comment by Robby Cornelissen answered the question:

```
ng build && scp -r dist/* whatever.com:/wherever
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ng build command to build your application. To deploy your application you can define script in your package.json:

> "deploy": "node deploy.js"

Now you can have a deploy.js file in your app root where you can write code to pick the dist folder and copy where ever you want and then run npm deploy command.